# Transition between a standard view and UITabBarController view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios, uitabbarcontroller

What is the cleanest way to set up a structure where you have an initial standard, full screen UIView, which transitions to a Tab Bar view?

Answer (score 0):

Add the tab bar view as a subview to the window. Then show the fullscreen view (controller) by presenting it as a modal view (controller) over the tab bar. Remove the fullscreen view with an animation by dismissing the modal view.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I agree. Displaying ordinary UIView over a UITabBarController view as modal is probably the cleanest way. But you could alternatively do a flip view transition if you don't want to use modal view.